Can't start XAMPP MariaDB potentially because of databases size sum limit
I use my XAMPP for apache and mariadb, to get the localhost and import database so I can work on the sites frontend.
I have a recurring problem, where my XAMPP (Version 8.2.12) MariaDB (Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.32-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64), source revision c4143f909528e3fab0677a28631d10389354c491) stops working, usually when I shut it down and try to start it again but it fails. Now this has been keep happening for every month(i'm guessing it's the size of databases or some ibdata, ibtmp they generate)  so, where I either shut it down and can't start or myPhpAdmin is not working and restarting fails. This I fixed usually by copying backup contents in xampp/mysql to /data, there were various solutions I tried found on stackoverflow but ultimately it still keeps happening and I'm unable keep the databases, so I need to import them again.
I dont know if it's related but when I was on Windows 10 everything worked fine for years once I clean installed Win11 this recurring problem started another thing could be the newer XAMPP(and it's modules) version.
mysql_error.log
2024-05-23 23:33:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2024-05-23 23:33:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2024-05-23 23:33:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.3
2024-05-23 23:33:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2024-05-23 23:33:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2024-05-23 23:33:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2024-05-23 23:33:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2024-05-23 23:33:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence number 526409885 in the system tablespace does not match the log sequence number 1075268620 in the ib_logfiles!
2024-05-23 23:33:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2024-05-23 23:33:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2024-05-23 23:33:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2024-05-23 23:33:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2024-05-23 23:33:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2024-05-23 23:33:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2024-05-23 23:33:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.32 started; log sequence number 1075268620; transaction id 1068489
2024-05-23 23:33:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2024-05-23 23:33:11 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-05-23 23:33:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240523 23:33:11
2024-05-23 23:33:11 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.

I also tried changing mysql.ini to no success, tried increasing sizes, adding variations of this, which made mysql unable start at all or fail later:
innodb_temp_data_file_path=ibtmp1:50M:autoextend:max:500M

Any help appreciated!


you have mariadb, not mysql. No, the two are not the same 2) your log file does not contain any errors, just a normal, clean startup. 3) unfortunately, there is no information in your question that would enable us to tell you why your mariadb database crashes 4) database crashing is not a programming problem, but a database operation one. This question is off topic here on SO.


I don't see a log of a startup failing, so its hard to give any advice as to what is wrong. What is wrong is the numerous SO answers that prescribe removing file or restoring partial directories. If you have done this, restore from logical backup. The large log sequence number is odd, but could be a result of manual moving so I'm not reading too much into it.

@danblack Not sure what is "logical" backup, but mysql backup folder I copy and rename to data ( delete the old data, first) works that I can start mysql again and import a databases until something fills up and it doesnt start anymore...

A logical backup is mariadb-dump/mysqldump. The moving of folders is a physical restore. Show the log of the failure.


Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M

That is so tiny that I would expect it to fail.  How much RAM is available to MariaDB?  Change innodb_buffer_pool_size to be about 70% of available space.

... :max:500M

Puts a limit on disk usage for the file in question.  This may or may not be in your best interest.  How much disk space do you have/
